# Simple Python API Call Not Working

Tags: python, api, post

I am having trouble making a simple API call. Hoping I can get some assistance. I have tried several variations of this request but I keep getting the same result. I've tried many solutions from previous requests posted on this site but none seem to help me.

The request I am attempting to make:

```
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

url = "https://api.ramcoams.com/api/v2/"

headers = {'Key': 'My_Key', 'operation':'GetEntityTypes'}

response = requests.post( url, headers=headers, verify=False)

print(response.text)
```

The response I get is:

```
{"ResponseCode":400,"ResponseText":"Key parameter missing."}
```

Lastly the documentation for the API is [here:](https://higherlogicdownload.s3.amazonaws.com/RUG/7e311f78-1f40-43c2-840d-b034bb4203be/UploadedFiles/2cYeD4kUQTiSvtroEOG2_ramco_api_v2_doc.pdf)

Comment: Are you sure it wants `Key` as a header or as post data, e.g. `requests.post(url, data=headers, verify=False)`?

Comment: not sure at all. literally my first attempt. Just tried this and it worked. Thanks friend!